# Super-absorbent Polymers

Tags: reaction-mechanism, polymers

I want to cast a cube out of super-absorbent powder (Fake Snow) for an art piece, and make it become shapeless by gradually exposing it to water over 7 days. I have 2 questions:

- What is the best type of glue that I can use to stick it together while keeping it exposable to water + keeping them together after expansion?
- Would it expand with slowly dripping water over 7 days? (All the videos I watched recommend "pouring water as quickly as possible")

Comment: 1. this is two questions.  2. could you elaborate your questions with more detail of what you want?